# Blackberry How to get the current home background uri?

Tags: java, blackberry

I'd like to know how I can get the uri of the current background image of a blackberry.

I need this because I want to edit this picture and then set it as the home screens background again. The edit I want to make is to put text on the image.

So basically I want to perform these steps:

1. Get the uri of the current
   background of the main screen.
2. Create a new bitmap based on the
   background.
3. Add text to the bitmap
4. Save the new bitmap and set it as the home background

So, does anyone knows how to get the background uri of the home screen? (not the application background).

Answer (score 0):

You can't get background image. [HomeScreen](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.0.0api/net/rim/blackberry/api/homescreen/HomeScreen.html) class in the API lets you only to set the background image. To give you an idea, several applications that adds text to background was pushing users to select the background first. I recommend you to do so and after first run of your application, you can save the path.